# Installing Sitecore 9.0.2 SIF generates wrong marketingdefinitions_master configuration

Tags: solr, configuration, sitecore-install-framework

After configuring SIF installer for Sitecore 9.0.2 installation as follows

```
# Start Install
Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework
$prefix = "foo"
...

#install solr cores for sitecore
$solrParams = @{
  Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"
  SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
  SolrRoot = $SolrRoot
  SolrService = $SolrService
  CorePrefix = $prefix
}
...
```

It generates cores inside Solr with correct prefix, however, when I navigate to Content Editor, I'm getting following error `Index sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master was not found`, and after inspecting `Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Web.config` and `Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Master.config` I've noticed that the configuration is pointing to wrong core id.

```
<index id="sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">`
```

What makes me think is the root of the problem above.

The question is - why does that happen and how do I fix that? As everything seemed to be correctly declared in SIF config and other sub-configs.

Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently that is correct core id, as it's exact the same on the other instance of Sitecore which is working, so now, I am completely puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out everything was correct in the config, the reason for it for not working was an underpowered machine. As during the installation process, it was timing out in some of the steps, therefore creating a chain reaction of very obvious error messages. So, as soon as I switched to a more powerful machine, and executed installation process with exact same configuration files, everything worked flawlessly without a single error message. Altho, during one of the attempts, was getting an exact same error message, but that was due to the misconfigured xconnect path in commerce installation file.